# Can I call ASP.NET RegSQL from code?

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership

Is it possible to call (the equivalent of) aspnet_regsql.exe from managed code?  My idea is to create a class to automagically build the database for an installed web app, which uses the ASP.NET Membership provider.  I could probably call aspnet_regsql.exe direct from code, but I came across the RegSql class(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229567.aspx)  - unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any methods...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RegSql class lives inside aspnet_regsql.exe. It's the entry point for the console application, so it has a static `Main(string[])` method.

Following the usage [instructions for aspnet_regsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(VS.80).aspx) we can pass it the parameters it expects. (something like `"-S localhost -U user -P password"`). Input parameters are split by a space (' ').

Comment: Thanks for that.  I missed the Main method.  Input parameters can also be in a string array (new string[] { "-S", "localhost", ...})